# Request from BOTO failing after making request from AWS CPP sdk

Tags: boto, aws-sdk-cpp

my application is making request to AWS dynamodb using AWS CPP Sdk, and after that other request is sent from BOTO to dynamodb, but it fails with below error:

ssl.SSLError: _ssl.c:319: Invalid SSL protocol variant specified.

how can i resolve it.

Appreciate the help